# Converting text to image on hover

Tags: css, html

im trying to convert text to image on hover, everything works good but image is not converting fully. Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/kvmyb4ot/2/

Html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
         <a href="ArchitectureWork.html">
             <img src="http://milenanimuje.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/animacja.png" width="160" height="160" alt="">
         </a>
         <a href="ArchitectureWork.html"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Tekst1</h3></a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-item > a:first-child         { display: none; }
.flex-item:hover > a:first-child   { display: inline; }
.flex-item:hover > a:last-child    { display: none; }
.flex-container                    { display: flex; }
.flex-item{
background:#f0dcdd;
animation-name: bounceInLeft;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
padding-top: 70px !important;
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
padding-left: 70px;
padding-right: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for response, i want to my image on hover fill full box.

Comment: Firstly, remove the fixed size you have in the HTML....I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks for help @Paulie_D, now my image is very big: https://jsfiddle.net/yau3dwjg/
I can resize it but now i have big borders, is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should refacto your padding rules to : `padding: 70px`
and add a new rule : `.flex-item:hover { padding: 0 }`

Comment: This! That was so easy, and i not figured it out... Thanks :)